# python: slow timeit() function

Tags: python, timer, timeit

When I run the code below outside of timeit(), it appears to complete instantaneously.  However when I run it within the timeit() function, it takes much longer.  Why?

```
>>> import timeit
>>> t = timeit.Timer("3**4**5")
>>> t.timeit()
16.55522028637718
```

Using:
Python 3.1 (x86) - 
AMD Athlon 64 X2 - 
WinXP (32 bit)

Comment: Paging Alex Martelli, Alex Martelli, please comment on python timeit module...

Comment: RichieHindle already got it right while I was offline. And, I always use "python -mtimeit" anyway, never timeit within the interactive interpreter or a program;-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `timeit()` function runs the code many times (default one million) and takes an average of the timings.

To run the code only once, do this:

```
t.timeit(1)
```

but that will give you skewed results - it repeats for good reason.

To get the per-loop time having let it repeat, divide the result by the number of loops.  Use a smaller value for the number of repeats if one million is too many:

```
count = 1000
print t.timeit(count) / count
```

Comment: Yep!  I also recommend using `python -mtimeit` from a command line instead of timeit as a module -- the command line version has just too many handy little things you don't get from the module (repeating a varying number of times depending on how slow/fast is what you're measuring, for example: a great microbenchmarking technique, pity the module doesn't offer it -- etc, etc;-).

Comment: @Alex Your comment here isn't clear to me. Can you clarify what extra functionality is available on the CLI.

Comment: @Tshepang: CLI use of timeit picks the number of repetitions "magically" -- few for slow code being measured, more for faster code, a lot for very fast code -- nicely balancing accuracy and time it takes to get results.

Comment: @Alex: now that's totally kool. Thanks for sharing. This piece of info should be more explicitly stated a bit better in the lib reference. Anyways, you also made it sound like there's other nifty features; what are those?

Comment: @Alex: "the command line version has just too many handy little things you don't get from the module" was as if there was more; maybe it's nitpicking, but can you clarify that part (or just edit it out).

Comment: @Tshepang: Run `python -mtimeit -h` to get full documentation.  (And Alex can't edit his comment - comments are only editable for a short time after they are first created.)

Answer (score 6):

Because timeit defaults to running it one million times.  The point is to do micro-benchmarks, and the only way to get accurate timings of short events is to repeat them many times.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html), Timer.timeit() runs your code one million times by default.  Use the "number" parameter to change this default:

```
t.timeit(number=100)
```

for example.

Answer (score 2):

[Timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit) runs for one million loops by default.

You also may have order of operations issues: `(3**4)**5 != 3**4**5`.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Very helpful.  And yes, that was the intended order of operations.